# Ansible change default value according to a condition

Tags: ansible

Is it possible to change a role variable default value according to some condition (i.e. the value of another variable)?

## Details

I have two related variables for a command, `env` and `composer_opts`.

If both are left at default (`env = "prod"` and `composer_opts = "--no-dev"`) everything is ok.

If I change `env` to `dev`, the default for the other one will break my command, so I always need to set both. Would it be possible to avoid this by setting a conditional default value with a custom script / if?

Important: I don't want to **always** set the `composer_opts` value according to the `env` value. I want to set it only if it's not already set (i.e. a dynamic default value).

## Pseudocode

I would like to do something like this (following code is not valid, just pseudocode to express my need)

```
---
# defaults/main.yml

env: prod
composer_opts: 
    when: "{{env}}" = 'prod'
        '--no-dev --optimize-autoloader --no-interaction'
    when: "{{env}}" = 'dev'
        ''
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I suggest this solution:

```
---
 - set_fact:
     composer_opts: ""
   when: "{{env}}" == 'dev'
```

It will set `composer_opts` variable to string `""` when variable `env` is equal to '`dev`'.

Here is example of playbook based on updated question:

```
$ cat test.yml

---
- hosts: 127.0.0.1
  connection: local
  tasks:
  - set_fact:
      composer_opts: "{% if env == 'prod' %} '--no-dev --optimize-autoloader --no-interaction' {% else %} '' {% endif %}"

  - debug: var=composer_opts
```

Sample output:

```
sudo ansible-playbook test.yml -e env=dev

PLAY [127.0.0.1] ************************************************************** 

GATHERING FACTS *************************************************************** 
ok: [127.0.0.1]

TASK: [set_fact ] ************************************************************* 
ok: [127.0.0.1]

TASK: [debug var="{{composer_opts}}"] ***************************************** 
ok: [127.0.0.1] => {
    "var": {
        " '' ": " '' "
    }
}

PLAY RECAP ******************************************************************** 
127.0.0.1                  : ok=3    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0   


sudo ansible-playbook test.yml -e env=prod

PLAY [127.0.0.1] ************************************************************** 

GATHERING FACTS *************************************************************** 
ok: [127.0.0.1]

TASK: [set_fact ] ************************************************************* 
ok: [127.0.0.1]

TASK: [debug var="{{composer_opts}}"] ***************************************** 
ok: [127.0.0.1] => {
    "var": {
        " '--no-dev --optimize-autoloader --no-interaction' ": " '--no-dev --optimize-autoloader --no-interaction' "
    }
}

PLAY RECAP ******************************************************************** 
127.0.0.1                  : ok=3    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0
```

Comment: This is a part of the solution. It will always set `composer_opts` to empty string when `env` is "dev", overwriting any actual value set. I think the conditional should be extended like this: `when: "{{env}}" == 'dev' and "{{composer_opts}}" is undefined`. Does it looks good? Can you udpate your question accordingly?

Comment: composer_opts will be defined because it have it's default value. You need another expression to solve your task. For example variable custom_composer_opts.

Comment: Please elaborate with pseudocode what do you want to do. I will update my answer accordingly.

Comment: I have updated my question with additional explanation and pseudocode sample. Thank you.

Comment: I have updated my answer. Check it. I believe i understood what you need.

Comment: Excellent! Apart from a minor syntax issue on the debug statement, it does exactly what I need. Thank you!

Comment: This solution has precedence issues. A fact is not a default.

Answer (score 7):

While [@Navern's answer](https://serverfault.com/a/715772) does work, I found the embedded Jinja2 notation (`"{% if env == 'prod' %} ...`) to be extremely susceptible to notation and thus rather fragile. For example, when wrapping the line in question for better readability such as in this **untested code**:

```
composer_opts: >
               "{% if env == 'prod' %}
                   '--no-dev --optimize-autoloader --no-interaction'
                {% else %}
                   ''
                {% endif %}"
```

I ended up with unexpected results, such as additional whitespace or `\n` in `composer_opts`.

The approach I use is much dumber, but also more stable:

```
- name: set composer_opts for dev env
  set_fact:
     composer_opts: ''
     when: "{{env}}" == 'dev'

- name: set composer_opts for prod env
  set_fact:
     composer_opts: '--no-dev --optimize-autoloader --no-interaction'
     when: "{{env}}" == 'prod'
```

I also found [this blog post](http://everythingshouldbevirtual.com/ansible-using-set_facts-module) to be useful which essentially follows the same approach.

Comment: @sec if you use `|` instead of `>` you might not have the whitespace problem. (or you'll get more of it LOL)

Comment: @sec Use '>-' and check out the ansible spec.  It has many options for correctly manipulating multiline strings.  https://yaml-multiline.info/  Note, in particular, the block chomping indicator.

Comment: Note that this solution also had precedence issues.  A fact is not a default.

Answer (score 3):

Ansible set_fact based on condition in one liner :

```
- name: "set composer_opts based on environment"
  set_fact:
     composer_opts:  "{{ '--no-dev --optimize-autoloader --no-interaction' if (env == 'prod') else '' }}"
```

Comment: Same precedence issues as the other solutions ( a fact is not a default), however, if you put this condiional right in your defaults.yml file, this solution will work.  It gets real ugly real fast if you have a number of defaults dependent on the condition

Comment: IMO, we can have the variable in global vars file so that it could be imported wherever it is required.

Comment: Imported how?  That doesn't change the precedence.  In particular, this fact will override host vars, unlike a default.  You could add a condition though: `when: composer_opts is not defined` or something to that effect.

Answer (score 0):

```
- name:
```

set_fact:
path_install: |
{% if reportviewer_state == 'absent' and reportviewer_handler[reportviewer_package].name == 'ReportViewer_2010.exe' %}
C:\Windows\System32\msiexec.exe
{% else %}
{{ url_base_repository }}{{ reportviewer_handler[reportviewer_package].name }}
{% endif %}

- name: "install {{ reportviewer_handler[reportviewer_package].name }}"
  win_package:
  path: "{{ path_install | replace('\n', '') }}"
  state: "{{ reportviewer_state }}"
  product_id: "{{ reportviewer_handler[reportviewer_package].product_id }}"
  arguments: "{{ reportviewer_handler[reportviewer_package].arguments }}"

Comment: I think it would be good to add some more context around this answer